# How loop drop down value using Selenium JAVA

Tags: java, selenium

I have a dropdown with some countries as follows,

[image]

I want to send the values US,CA,AF,AL,DZ,AS,AD to an array, loop it and print by using Selenium and Java.

I tried the following

```
WebElement elementdrop = d.findElement(By.xpath("path"));
List<WebElement> dropdownvalues = d.findElements(By.xpath("path"));
for(WebElement value:dropdownvalues)
{ 
  String pcvalues=value.getText();
  System.out.println("value names" + pcvalues);
 }
```

This will print United States Canada Afghanistan Albania etc. But I want like US CA AF AL DZ AS AD

Comment: Could you share the what have you done for the same,issues you were facing? Its pretty straight forward question!!

Comment: The above drop down contain the list of countries.
In  this list each country name have corresponding id like US,CA, AF etc.
I want this ids to an array.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Could you share your code and issues you faced?

Comment: I tried like this,

WebElement elementdrop = d.findElement(By.xpath("path"));
List<WebElement> dropdownvalues = d.findElements(By.xpath("path"));
 for(WebElement value:dropdownvalues)
 {
  String pcvalues=value.getText();
  System.out.println("value names" + pcvalues);
 }
 
 
 This will print 
 United States
 Canada
 Afghanistan
 Albania
 etc.
 
 But I want like
 US
 CA
 AF
 AL
 DZ
 AS
 AD

Answer (score 3):

```
 WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.name("Country"));

 List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

 Iterator<WebElement> it=options.iterator();

   while(it.hasNext())
    {
      System.out.println(it.next().getAttribute("Value"));
    }
```

Give this a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Also I need to do some thing like this. I have the country code stored in one variable like
String CODE = "CA";
then, I need to check whether the CODE is available in dropdown.
If it available ,
print System.out.println("Country available to choose"); 
else
print System.out.println("Country not available to choose");
Could you please modify this code for this issue?

Comment: String CODE = "CA";
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.name("Country"));
 List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
 Iterator<WebElement> it=options.iterator();
   while(it.hasNext())
    {
      if(it.next().getAttribute("Value")==CODE){
  print System.out.println("Country available to choose"); 
      }
      else
 {
   print System.out.println("Country not available to choose"); 
 }
    }

Comment: Yeah you can do that whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: I have list of country codes.
I want to check whether these country codes are matching with 
the drop down value.

Comment: You might have to brush up on coding skills. In this scenario as you have the value you should be able to use it for your calculation. Looking at your code what i see is you could use 'equalsIgnoreCase' instead of== that should resolve your issue.